# Can't create contact list

Tags: xdb, sitecore-api, xconnect

I couldn't create contacts list and getting following exception,

HTTP POST
URL http://x/sitecore/api/ssc/ListManagement/ContactList

```
Exception Sitecore.XConnect.XdbSearchUnavailableException: The HTTP response was
 not successful: InternalServerError
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.SearchWebApiClient.<Search>d__9`1.MoveNext
()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Operations.SearchOperationInvoker.<Execute>d__2.M
oveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.SearchHelpers.<ExecuteSearch>d__6`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.SearchDefinition`1.<Execute>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.AsyncSearchHitEnumerator`1.<Create>d__8.MoveNext(
)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.AsyncEntityQueryProvider.<ExecuteAsync>d__8`1.Mov
eNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Comment: Have you checked xConnect logs? It should give you more detail on what exactly failed during search.

Comment: I can't see those logs, I got this from log option in SIM, I had 7 other options there but none of them has xconnect in name, the others are following,
Client.log, Crawling.log, Fxm.log, Owin.log, Publishing.log, Search.log, WebDAV.log

Comment: @grg, very good call to check the xConnect logs. I had a InternalServerError and the cause was an expired license. I updated the one of the Sitecore website but not the xConnect one.

Comment: @jflheureux, it's good to hear that you made it work. You can write a short answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: My error was not about contact lists. All the Sitecore xConnect calls were logged as errors in Sitecore logs. Hence why I only added a comment to stress the importance of checking the xConnect logs for any xConnect InternalServerError in the Sitecore logs.